ALSA errors and stutter when using espeak
When I execute $ espeak test I sometimes get these errors and stutter in playback, things that I notice sometimes fix it are:

rebooting
unplugging and plugging back in the usb connection for my dac
restarting the user services for pipewire, pipewire-pulse, and wireplumber

I'm making this post when the latter two are not working
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:567:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:404:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:404:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1036:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:481:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:481:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:567:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1520
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1852
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1520
Expression 'ValidateParameters( outputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_Out )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1852


